# Rails: How do you access the value from a jQuery Mobile slider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to access the value that a user chooses by manipulating the jQuery Mobile slider.  For example, I have a slider that ranges from 1 to 10.  The user moves the slider to 5.  How can I send that '5' to a controller?

I've read through about 10 separate examples, and they all gloss over how to actually access the data from the slider.

Is a params hash created?  Do I need to put the slider within a form_for Rails element?  Any examples of actually using the value from a jQuery Mobile slider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/99AfX/

```
$('#btn').live('click',function(){
      alert($('#slider-0').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_slider_id').change(function(){console.log(this.value)});
```